# Stuck at the end with a trigonometric series

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, trigonometric-series

Check the identity:

$$\prod\limits_{0\le k\le n-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}+x\right)=\frac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n-1}}$$

$$t^n-1=\prod\limits_{0\le k\le n-1}\big(t-e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}\big)$$

Let $t=e^{i\theta}$. In the following I have used that $|1-e^{i\theta}|=2|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}|$

$\text{LHS}=e^{in\theta}-1\Rightarrow|\text{LHS}|=2|\sin\frac{n\theta}{2}|$

Now we will work on the expression

$A=e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta}e^{i(\frac{2k\pi}{n}-\theta)}=e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta}e^{i(\frac{2k\pi}{n}-\theta)}=e^{i\theta}\big(1-e^{i(\frac{2k\pi}{n}-\theta)}\big)$

$\Rightarrow |A|=2|\sin\big(\frac{k\pi}{n}-\frac{\theta}{2}\big)|$

$\Rightarrow|\text{RHS}|=2^n\big|\prod\limits_{0\le k\le n-1}\sin\big(\frac{k\pi}{n}-\frac{\theta}{2}\big)\big|$

$|\text{LHS}|=|\text{RHS}|\Rightarrow\big|\prod\limits_{0\le k\le n-1}\sin\big(\frac{k\pi}{n}-\frac{\theta}{2}\big)\big|=\frac{|\sin\frac{n\theta}{2}|}{2^{n-1}}$

Taking $\theta=-2x\Rightarrow\big|\prod\limits_{0\le k\le n-1}\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{n}+x\big)\big|=\frac{|\sin(nx)|}{2^{n-1}}$

How do I get rid of the absolute value?

Thanks for the help.

P.S. I suggest viewing with ×2 magnifier because the exponentials get tiny.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by $t^n-1=0\implies\dots$ The product after is true whether $t^n-1=0$ or not.

Comment: Also, what is $A$ supposed to be? Does $A$ depends on $k?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That is equivalent with let $t$ be the n-th root of unity. I was just providing context.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, $A$ depends on $k$.

Comment: Well, using notation where language would be clearer is not so much providing context as providing confusion.

Comment: $$e^{in\theta}-1=2ie^{in\theta/2}\sin\frac{n\theta}2$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have edited I hope it is clearer now + what if $sin\frac{n\theta}{2}<0$ ? It cannot be an absolute value right?

Comment: Ah so you're saying to not use abs value anymore?

Comment: That would be my suggestion, yes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I managed to prove using your suggestion! Thanks. But now I have to calculate another product using this product. Can you also help me on that one pls? (I will post another question). I got that it makes $0$ but it shouldn't be $0$.